# Extract name in a text file between (: or , or ; ) and (keyword) with regex in python

Tags: python, regex, path, keyword

```
# coding=utf-8
import re
f = open('/Users/.../example.txt')
mensaje = f.read()
mensaje = mensaje.replace("\n","")
keywords_cap = ['SpA','SPA','LIMITADA','LTDA','S.A.']
keywords_cap = map(re.escape, keywords_cap)
keywords_cap.sort(key=len, reverse=True)
obj = re.compile(r'\s*([^:]*)(?<!\w)(?:{})'.format('|'.join(keywords_cap)))
print("COMPANY NAME: %s" % obj.findall(mensaje))
```

I have different files that contains `:` or `;`, the company name, and one word defined in `keywords_cap`.

The file contains:

```
Nombre o razón social: "MJ FACILITIES SERVICES SpA nombre de fantasía MJ SpA."
```

Now my output is:

```
MJ FACILITIES SERVICES SpA nombre de fantasía
```

and I only want `MJ FACILITIES SERVICES SpA`.

Comment: Can you try this? _obj = re.compile(r'\s*([^:]*?)(?<!\w)(?:{})'.format('|'.join(keywords_cap)))_

Comment: Do you want to extract a substring between `:`/`,`/`;`/`.` and a word from `keywords_cap`?

Answer (score 0):

You may match the starting boundary first, with `[:,;.]`, then consume any whitespaces and an optional `"` char to "ltrim" the result (with `\s*"?`), then match and capture any 0+ chars other than those delimiters, as few as possible, up to one of your `keywords_cap`:

```
obj = re.compile(r'[:,;.]\s*"?([^:,;.]*?(?<!\w)(?:{}))'.format('|'.join(keywords_cap)))
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/VP4APa) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OhUlrb/3).

**Details**

- `[:,;.]` - a `:`, `,`, `;` or `.`
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespace chars
- `"?` - an optional `"`
- `([^:,;.]*?(?<!\w)(?:{}))` - Capturing group 1 (this is what `re.findall` will return):

  - `[^:,;.]*?` - any zero or more chars other than `:`, `,`, `;`, and `.`, as few as possible (`*?` is a lazy quantifier)
  - `(?<!\w)` - no word char immediately to the left is allowed
  - `(?:{})` - the alternation group with escaped `keyword_cap` items.

Comment: If the words of the keyword are repeated more than once in my file, how can I take only the first result?

Comment: @AnnC Do you mean you need to only obtain the first match? See [this demo](https://ideone.com/aUWIqm). Use `m = obj.search(mensaje)` to get the first match data object, and `if m:` to see if the match is a success, then grab the Group 1 value using `m.group(1)`.

Comment: I do not know if it is possible, but I would like to start extracting text when they start the upper case of the words to be extracted. Also also taking into account; :, or ..

Comment: Could you please update the question to include sample strings with expected output and why this output is expected?

Comment: @AnnC Also, please check if [`[:,;.]\s*"?([A-Z]\w*(?:\s+[A-Z]\w*)*?\s+(?:LIMITADA|S\.A\.|LTDA|SpA|SPA))`](https://regex101.com/r/OhUlrb/4) works for you once you get a couple of example strings.